# How to setup HDD autosuspend in Ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive

In Windows there is power management feature which allow operating system turn off hard disk when there is no activity in this hard disk for a certain time.

However when I switch to Ubuntu I don't find this feature on power management setting.

Even if I unmount the hard disk, the hard disk is still spinning. Is there any tools, drivers, command to enable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Download the app called **Disks**

> sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility

Open it, select the menu button on top right. Select **Drive Setting**. On **Stanby** tab active the **Apply Standby Timeout Settings**, set your preffered time interval and press OK. Enter your password to authenticate the operation.

Then go to the next (**APM**) tab, active it. Make sure APM level is not more than 127. Press OK and again authenticate the operation using password.

Comment: However, it doesn't work for mobile hard disk. Is that caused by lacking of driver?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want this for main hdd. It is probably by design. No Linux based OS I've ever used thought spinning down laptop hdd when not used for prolonged time is necessary. So they probably think the same about spinning down portable hdd.